# Can I use more than two istream overload operator?

Tags: visual-c++

I tried to implement two istream operator in one project. But, the compiler error saying that the function is already defined and can't be duplicated.

```
// Overloaded operator Input
istream &operator >>(istream &input, College &C) {
    getline(input, C.name);
    return input;
}

istream &operator >> (istream &input, College &C) {
    input >> C.rank >> C.getYear >> C.website >> C.transfer >> 
C.retention >> C.cost >> C.getNoStu;
    return input;
}
```

So for the first operator, I only need to take input for one variable. But, for the second operator, I need to take more than one variable.

Comment: This is not different from other functions. You can't have two functions with the same name and the same arguments.

Comment: Short answer, no, but there is nothing preventing you from implementing a different function that you would call a different way. `College c; c.inputName(std::cin);` as an example.